# how can I change where value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, loops

```
id  o_num   d_num
69af4bf986c4df522afb54da6512bdc5    5   5
69af6111de53b550b0d13f86398b59e5    19  19
69b264c4b93a1984450689b16807b293    10  10
69b26c0fb38ff1cd2d4b01696aa14883    20  20
69b5c46bdc8a8f49f913d9d2325f0a76    15  15
69b71276a69dece5630ed3405ceca411    1   6
69b790c7937602e8fd52bc4d28194625    5   17
69b7bfde4effdaf31d362165a23a8dd0    4   13
69b93626a799636aef2ab3567cf3a110    14  14
```

I have a table like this, there are total 20 `o_num` in the table, and i want to select all the row that `o_num` is 1 then group by the `d_num` to count the id number, and them change the `o_num` to 2, until `o_num` to 20. and the result is in one table.

here is my code for 1 time:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), o_num, d_num
FROM table1
WHERE o_num = 1
GROUP BY o_num, d_num
```

### how can i change the code to get my table

I want get the reselt like this，a table with 3 columns

```
sum o_num d_num
9 1 1
8 1 2
4 1 3
……
5 1 20
4 2 1
6 2 2
8 2 3
……
3 2 20
5 3 1
……
……
2 20 20
```

Comment: Can you explain that better? How would your desired result look like?

Comment: In code, there is no instance of table T_T. How are you using that T_T?

Comment: What is the problem if you drop WHERE condition from your query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, i add the desired result

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński that seems make sense!